# How to concatenate the "overflow" of fields with character limits

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 3 address fields and each address field has a limit of 100 characters each.

I need to create a query to make the maximum character limit for each address field to be 30 characters long.  If one address field is > 30 then I'll cut off the rest, but take the remainder and concatenate it onto the beginning of the next address field.  I would do this until the last address field (address3) is filled up and then just get rid of the remainder on the last address field.

Is there a way to do this with an SQL query or with T-SQL?

Comment: What would be in the second and third field if all three address parts used a total of 15 characters?

Comment: So if address1 were 15 characters I would leave it as-is.  But if address2 was 35 I would put those last 5 characters on the beginning of address3.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes it a lot harder.  Let me see if I can some up with something.

Comment: So in the example I provided below, woudl the desired output be `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123  | 456789second part   | third part`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd go with the problem description, and write something that's "obviously" correct (provided I've understood your spec :-))

```
/* Setup data - second example stolen from Abe, first just showing that it works with short enough data */
declare @t table (ID int not null,Address1 varchar(100) not null,Address2 varchar(100) not null,Address3 varchar(100) not null)
insert into @t (ID,Address1,Address2,Address3)
values (1,'abc','def','ghi'),
(2,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789 ', 'second part', 'third part')

/* Actual query - shift address pieces through the address fields, but only to later ones */
;with Shift1 as (
    select
        ID,SUBSTRING(Address1,1,30) as Address1,SUBSTRING(Address1,31,70) as Address1Over,Address2,Address3
    from @t
), Shift2 as (
    select
        ID,Address1,SUBSTRING(Address1Over+Address2,1,30) as Address2,SUBSTRING(Address1Over+Address2,31,70) as Address2Over,Address3
    from Shift1
), Shift3 as (
    select
        ID,Address1,Address2,SUBSTRING(Address2Over+Address3,1,30) as Address3
    from Shift2
)
select * from Shift3
```

Result:

```
ID            Address1                          Address2                          Address3
----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
1           abc                                 def                                ghi
2           abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234   56789 second part                 third part
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify what to do with very short addresses, but my first crack at it would be something like this:

```
with temp as
(
  select 1 id, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789' part1, 'second part' part2, 'third part' part3
),
 concated as
(
  SELECT id, part1 + part2 + part3 as whole
  FROM temp
)
select  id, 
        SUBSTRING(whole, 0, 30) f, 
        SUBSTRING(whole, 30,30) s, 
        SUBSTRING(whole, 60,30) t 
from concated
```

This returns:

```
id  | f                               | s                            | t
1   | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123   | 456789second partthird part  |
```

If that's not what you're looking for please specify the desired output for the above.

**UPDATE:**

Well... this appears to work but it's pretty gross.  I'm sure someone can come up with a better solution.

```
with temp as
(
  select 1 id, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789 ' part1, 'second part' part2, 'third part' part3
)
select  id, 
        SUBSTRING(part1, 0, 30) f, 
        SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(part1, 30, 70) + SUBSTRING(part2, 0,30),0,30) s, 
        SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(part1, 30, 70) + SUBSTRING(part2, 0,30),30,70),0,30) + SUBSTRING(part3, 0,30),0,30) t 
from temp
```

Comment: So the desired output here would be...  `id  | f                               | s                            | t
1   | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123   | 456789second part | third part`

Comment: Yah this is a good start.  I was looking for something a little more dynamic using T-SQL or something.  Maybe using cursors is needed.